# Why my jQuery code can run on jsfiddle but not on Dreamweaver or browser?

Tags: jquery, html, jsfiddle

My jQuery code can run on jsfiddle but not on Dreamweaver nor browser?
Here is the link to my code on JSfiddle, and below is my codes.
please help me check if there is something missing?
http://jsfiddle.net/sbmp3apz/6/

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>lab1</title>
</head>

<body>
pick your fruit:
<input type="text" id="newfruit">
<br>

<h1> Fruit Shelf:</h1>

<div id="div1">
    <ol id="fruits"></ol>
</div>

<h1>Basket:</h1

<ol id="basket"></ol>
<button>add fruit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
    var fruitslist = ["pear", "apple", "peach", "grapes", "strawberry", "melon"];
$( document ).ready(function() {

$.each(fruitslist, function(){
    $("<li>").text(this).appendTo("#fruits");
});


$('button').click(function () {
    var ipt = $("#newfruit").val();
    if(fruitslist.indexOf(ipt) > -1){
        $("<li>").text(ipt).appendTo("#basket");
        fruitslist = $.grep(fruitslist, function(value){
            return value != ipt;
        });
        $("#fruits > li").filter(function(){
            return $(this).text() === ipt;
        }).remove();
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Do you include the jquery souce file?

Comment: Move the click action in document.ready

Comment: @hjpotter92 yes i included

Comment: @karthikr I tried it, but it didn't work

Comment: Errors in the browser console?

Comment: did't try...don't no how to debug...

Comment: In the Fiddle **your entire JS code** runs `onLoad`. Is it the same when you run in a browser?

Comment: Wheres jquery? Go to tools->Javascript console in Chrome to see error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three things need to be pay attention:

1. Must load jQuery on your page. Like this: 
   `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>`
2. the jQuery lib position must load before your **script**.
3. your code must be wrapped used `$(function (){})`, or your code load after the DOM loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the JQuery framework (dependency) linked in the head before your own script:

http://puu.sh/bDukO.PNG

add this line to your html code directly underneath the head tag and before your own script:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

**Note** You dont need the 'type' attribute in script tags in HTML5 anymore

Comment: You are using Jquery 2.x edge in the JSfiddle but you referenced 1.11.1 in your own code

Comment: as you can see on the codes above, i added the jquery source...it still dosen't work...

Comment: What are your browser settings? Are you allowed to run local javascript files by default?

Comment: Run the local copy in your browser, press f12, screenshot or post any errors.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined  this is the only error, but It means jquery file not linked, but I included the source

Comment: i noticed you have 2 html tags in your doc, I am running it fine on my machine: http://puu.sh/bDvtd.png

Comment: thanks, the jQuery lib position must load before your script. I diddn't put the source link above my local js file, that's why, Thank you

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache? It might be caching the page and not updating the changes, run in incognito mode to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

You have an open tag in your example code.

Your example code (just line 21):

```
<h1>Basket:</h1
```

Should be

```
<h1>Basket:</h1>
```

It appears closed in your JSFiddle example.
Hope that helps.