# jQuery onclick doesn't work on my website but does on jsfiddle

Tags: jquery

Herru Stackoverflow!!

I'm new to jQuery. My code on JSfiddle works but it doesn't work on my website. I don't understand why my code (below) doesn't work on my website but does on jsfiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/vt9115vw/).

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#submenu").click(function () {
    $("#submenu-content").toggle();
});
</script>
<style> 
#mobile-elevator {
    background-color: #0079a8;
    color: white !important;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#mobile-elevator a {
    color: white !important;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
#mobile-elevator #button {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #E1E6FA;
}
#submenu-content {
    display: none;
}
</style>
<div id="mobile-elevator">  
    <div id="button">
        <span id="submenu">
            Productos
        </span>
    </div>
     <div id="submenu-content">
           Hello
    </div>
    <div id="button">
        <a href="">
            Ayuda
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="button">
        <a href="">
            Descargas
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="button" style="border-bottom: 0px solid black;">
        <a href="">
            Contacto
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm just trying to create a mobile navigation bar.

Comment: can you check with this i have updates your Fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/vt9115vw/1/` do let me know if it works on you site

Comment: Your question as same as this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25902930/why-my-jquery-code-can-run-on-jsfiddle-but-not-on-dreamweaver-or-browser/25903141#25903141

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `click` event inside `DOM ready` fucntion
like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#submenu").click(function () {
    $("#submenu-content").toggle();
});
});
```

If You see in `jsfiddle`,there are options to write function inside `domready` or `on load` etc.this is reason  `click` event works in `jsfiddle` not in your `website`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
function tog()
{
    $("#submenu-content").toggle();
}
```

Add a function 'tog' for toggle action. And assign your event handler function 'tog' using onclick element in the span with id = 'submenu'

```
    <span id="submenu" onclick='tog()' >
```

Answer (score 1):

always try to load `jQuery` and `JS` scripts at the end of page as if the `DOM` is not ready the script will not work. or you can wrap them inside -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //your code
});
```

as it will make the script to wait until the `DOM` is ready.